# I want to understand how Model binding using passed by value works

Tags: asp.net-mvc

got a tricky one here me thinks!

I want to understand how if this Cart object gets passed by value using the model binder, then how can it effect the actual value in the session?

```
  public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl) {
        Product product = repository.Products
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

        if (product != null) {
            cart.AddItem(product, 1);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }
```

Hope this explains my issue!

Thanks for any assistance

details

this bold code doesn't effect the customprofile in session

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, CustomProfile customProfile)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;


            membershipProvider.CreateUser(model, null, null, true, null,
                                          out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                const string message = "You have successfully reigestered, and you are now logged in.";
                authProvider.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

                var newCustomProfile = new CustomProfile(model.UserName);
                var db = new CrowdFundingDB();

                **customProfile = customProfileProvider.Create(newCustomProfile);**
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Basically if its passed by value, its my understanding that it creates a copy of the original value, and then if this copy is modified it won't effect the original value in the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cart` is not a *value type*, it's a *reference type*.

Passing it as an argument doesn't make a copy of the object, the method receives a copy of the reference to the actual object. It will access the same object through the copied reference.

See also: [ByRef vs ByVal Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383167/byref-vs-byval-clarification)

Comment: thx, what I dont get is how this is pass by reference:   

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

            // get the Cart from the session 
            Cart cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];
            // create the Cart if there wasn't one in the session data
            if (cart == null) {
                cart = new Cart();
                controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = cart;
            }
            // return the cart
            return cart;
        }

Comment: so how come this doesn't effect the custom profile in session:                public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, CustomProfile customProfile)
        { customProfile = customProfileProvider.Create(newCustomProfile);

Comment: @Quantum please post your code in your question. I'm not able to read it in the comments.