# a variable in a module triggers an error when called from a form

Tags: vb.net

I have a sub with two variables in a module. When called from the form, the second variable triggers the error "“Variable 'ala1' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime”. The result is a blank textbox. Would appreciate your help to find where my code is not correct. Here is my code:

**Module1**

```
Dim N10, N02b, A6, N07 As Double

Public Sub AxlPos(ByVal axl As Double, ByVal axla As String)
    If axl > (N10 - N02b / 1000) * modCos(A6) + N07  Then
        axla = "in section 1"
    ElseIf axl > (N10 - N02b / 1000) * modCos(A6) Then
        axla = "in section 2"
    ElseIf axl > (N10 / 1000) * modCos(A6) Then
        axla = "in section 3"
    Else
        axla = "in section 4"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Form1**

```
Dim N10, N02b, A6, N07, al1 As Double
Dim ala1 as string

Private Sub btnSolve_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSolve.Click
   axlpos(al1,ala1)
   Txtala1.Text = ala1
End sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to change your sub to a function returning a string.

```
Dim N10, N02b, A6, N07 As Double

Public Function AxlPos(ByVal axl As Double) as String
    Dim axla As String
    If axl > (N10 - N02b / 1000) * modCos(A6) + N07  Then
        axla = "in section 1"
    ElseIf axl > (N10 - N02b / 1000) * modCos(A6) Then
        axla = "in section 2"
    ElseIf axl > (N10 / 1000) * modCos(A6) Then
        axla = "in section 3"
    Else
        axla = "in section 4"
    End If
    return axla 
End Sub
```

And then call the function with

```
Dim N10, N02b, A6, N07, al1 As Double

Private Sub btnSolve_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSolve.Click
   Txtala1.Text = axlpos(al1)

End sub
```

The error is caused by the fact that at the point in which you call the method `AxlPos` the variable passed to the method (`ala1`) has not been assigned. The compiler warns you that this could cause a null reference exception in the code.
However it seems that you want to set the passed variable to a different value based in your calculations so the best approach is to create a function the return the calculated string value.

If you still want to use your approach then your code should be changed to

```
Private Sub btnSolve_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSolve.Click

   ala1 = String.Empty
   axlpos(al1,ala1)
   Txtala1.Text = ala1

End sub
```

but more important you should change the `ByVal` in a `ByRef` in the called module method

```
Public Sub AxlPos(ByVal axl As Double, ByRef axla As String)
```

See [ByVal vs ByRef clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383167/byref-vs-byval-clarification)

Comment: Both solutions are working well but the function option is of course smarter.  Many thanks.