# Why does the Default Property access the setter when removing an item

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

In the code below, when trying to remove an item from the `Cases` list the code breaks in the Setter with an index out of bounds. When running the debugger in VisualStudio 2017 it successfully goes through the `Remove()` function and deletes the last item but after returning to `Main()` it will break on the Setter and the call stack says it is coming from the Remove call. Example code below:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Cases As Collection = New Collection()
    Dim caseIndex As Integer = 2
    Cases.Remove(Cases(caseIndex))
End Sub

Public Class Collection

    Public WithEvents Cases As List(Of CaseClass)

    Public Sub New()
        Cases = New List(Of CaseClass)()
        Cases.Add(New CaseClass)
        Cases.Add(New CaseClass)
        Cases.Add(New CaseClass)
    End Sub

    Default Public Property BeltCase(ByVal Index As Integer) As CaseClass
        Get
            Return Cases(Index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As CaseClass)
            Cases(Index) = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub Remove(ByRef BeltCase As CaseClass)
        Cases.Remove(BeltCase)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CaseClass
    Public test As Int16
End Class
```

Call Stack:

> TestingVBBug.exe!TestingVBBug.Module1.Collection.set_BeltCase(Integer Index,TestingVBBug.Module1.CaseClass Value) Line 25   Basic
>     TestingVBBug.exe!TestingVBBug.Module1.Main() Line 6 Basic

So why would we be going through the Setter at all. And why does that happen after we exit the remove function?

Comment: See the article [The many cases of ByRef](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2010/01/21/the-many-cases-of-byref/) to learn that VB allows you to pass a Property ByRef which is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by your `Remove()` method, that is, you have a `ByRef` parameter *(for some reason)*. When you use `ByRef`, any changes made to the parameter inside the method must be reflected to the variable that was passed to the method. That happens by *reassigning* the value to the original variable.

In your case, it works like this:

- The `Remove()` method is called and a variable (`Cases(caseIndex)`) is passed to it.
- Some work is done inside the `Remove()` method which might, *or might not* include changing the value of the parameter `BeltCase`.
- The value of the parameter `BeltCase` gets reassigned to the variable that was originally passed to the method *(which is `Cases(caseIndex)`)*.
- As a result of the above step, the setter of the `BeltCase` property gets called with `Index = 2` which raises the out of range exception because `Cases(2)` doesn't exist (was removed).

To confirm, you can see this problem go away when you replace this line:

```
Cases.Remove(Cases(caseIndex))
```

..with:

```
Dim myCase As CaseClass = Cases(caseIndex)
Cases.Remove(myCase)
```

That way, you create a new variable which refers to the same `CaseClass` object and *most importantly* avoid calling the setter of your `Collection.BeltClase` property.

However, a better solution would be to not use `ByRef` in the first place *since you don't seem to need it in this situation*. So, simply use `Public Sub Remove(ByVal BeltCase As CaseClass)` instead.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4383167/4934172) for more about `ByVal` and `ByRef` with objects.

One last thing, please don't call your class `Collection` because it can be very confusing to anyone looking at your project.