# VBA Array function converts variable with a simple type to a value and does not store variable reference

Tags: arrays, vba, collections

VBA Array function converts variable with a simple type to a value and does not store variable reference. But if I pass a class variable it works as intended. Is it supposed to be like that or I'm missing something?

main module

```
Sub test()

Dim collection As collection
Set collection = New collection

Dim i As Long
Dim cl As New tst

i = 25
cl.i = 25

Debug.Print "Original i = " & i
Debug.Print "Original cl.i = " & cl.i
Debug.Print

collection.Add Item:=Array(i)
collection.Add Item:=Array(cl)

Debug.Print "i in array in collection: collection(1)(0) = " & collection(1)(0)
Debug.Print "i from class in array in collection: collection(2)(0).i = " & collection(2)(0).i
Debug.Print

i = i + 1
cl.i = cl.i + 1

Debug.Print "Adding: i = i + 1"
Debug.Print

Debug.Print "Original i = " & i ' 26
Debug.Print "Original cl.i = " & cl.i '26
Debug.Print

Debug.Print "i in array in collection: collection(1)(0) = " & collection(1)(0) '25, but I expect 26
Debug.Print "i from class in array in collection: collection(2)(0).i = " & collection(2)(0).i '26 correct
Debug.Print

End Sub
```

class tst

```
Public i As Long
```

Output

```
Original i = 25
Original cl.i = 25

i in array in collection: collection(1)(0) = 25
i from class in array in collection: collection(2)(0).i = 25

Adding: i = i + 1

Original i = 26
Original cl.i = 26

i in array in collection: collection(1)(0) = 25
i from class in array in collection: collection(2)(0).i = 26
```

Comment: Yes that's how it works.  Non-object variables are assigned by value, object variables are assigned by reference.

Comment: @TimWilliams I find this way of explaining things extremely confusing. `Collection.Add` does not care whether you're giving it an object or a value, it's receiving it `ByVal` either way.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I left my comment knowing you'd have a better explanation...  I do think it's worth distinguishing between the act of *assigning* and *passing* though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it supposed to be like that

Definitely. And the behavior is exactly the same regardless of whether you're passing a value or an object reference.

When you add `i` to the collection, *a copy of* the **value** (`ByVal`) of `i` is added to the collection; incrementing `i` will not increment the copy.

When you add `cl` to the collection, *a copy of* a **pointer** (also `ByVal`) to that object is added to the collection; modifying that pointer will not modify the copy in the collection either:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    Dim o As Class1
    Set o = New Class1
    Debug.Print VarPtr(o), ObjPtr(o)
    c.Add o
    Debug.Print VarPtr(c(1)), ObjPtr(c(1))
End Sub
```

This code outputs something like this:

```
 725937672     221317072 
 725937528     221317072
```

Note that the two pointers are different, but both are pointing to the same object reference.

If we affect the local copy of that object pointer locally...

```
Debug.Print VarPtr(o), ObjPtr(o)
c.Add o
Set o = Nothing
Debug.Print VarPtr(c(1)), ObjPtr(c(1))
Debug.Print VarPtr(o), ObjPtr(o)
```

The output is now as follows:

```
 725937672     221317072 
 725937528     221317072 
 725937672     0
```

We re-assigned `o` to `Nothing`, and yet the collection `c` *still* has a reference to the object! We didn't affect the object at all!

The `Public i` member of your test class was never copied anywhere, the collection doesn't even know/care about it: all the collection knows, is that it's holding a reference to an object.

So when you do `cl.i = 26`, you're not assigning anything the collection knows about. You're only saying "take the object at address X (the same `ObjPtr` held in the collection!), get its `i` property, and assign it the value 26": the collection's copy of the pointer was never updated.

When you do `i = 26`, you're not assigning anything the collection knows about either. You're saying "take the variable at address X (the local variable), assign it the value 26": the collection's copy of the value was never updated.

Comment: Upvoted. I swear I've seen you lay out the copy of the *value* vs. copy of the *pointer* somewhere before. I suspected as much, but definitely could not put an answer like this together. Thanks for the detail. I should be using `VarPtr` and `ObjPtr` more :-)

Comment: @BigBen [here, perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55405418/1188513)