# How to shorten common codes, method and properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, if-statement

In my frm_externalproduct I have this code

```
Select Case type
        Case "Internal"
            If frm_internal.editrow Then
                txtProduct.Enabled = False
                txtProduct.Text = frm_internal.pr_code
                txtDesc.Text = frm_internal.description
                txtUnit.Text = frm_internal.UOMstr
                txtQTY.Text = frm_internal.qty
                txtPurpose.Text = frm_internal.remarks
                uom_id = frm_internal.UOM
            End If

        Case "External"
            If frm_ExternalCanvass.editrow Then
                txtProduct.Enabled = False
                txtProduct.Text = frm_ExternalCanvass.pr_code
                txtDesc.Text = frm_ExternalCanvass.description
                txtUnit.Text = frm_ExternalCanvass.UOMstr
                txtQTY.Text = frm_ExternalCanvass.qty
                txtPurpose.Text = frm_ExternalCanvass.remarks
                uom_id = frm_ExternalCanvass.UOM
            End If
    End Select
    show_info(txtProduct.Text)
    txtQTY.Focus()
```

My question is how can I shorten this code? it's the same but it's different forms.

Comment: Create a base class that inherits `Form`, add public properties for `PrCode`, `Description`, ...etc, derive the `Internal` and `External` Forms from it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about optimising working code are off topic at SO.

Answer (score 1):

There is information missing to be able to provide the BEST solution (like object declarations and their underlying structure to start with) however using a generics, this will satisfy what you are attempting to do. You could move the lambda sub outside if there are more uses for it aside from this select case, however if not it is well served being secluded here.

```
Private Sub MyOriginalSub(parametersIfApplicable)
    '... Any missing code able the select statement

    dim setValues = Sub(o as object) 
            if o.editRow then
                txtProduct.Enabled = False
                txtProduct.Text = o.pr_code
                txtDesc.Text = o.description
                txtUnit.Text = o.UOMstr
                txtQTY.Text = o.qty
                txtPurpose.Text = o.remarks
                uom_id = o.UOM
            End If
        End sub

    Select Case type
        Case "Internal" : setValues(frm_internal)
        Case "External" : setValues(frm_ExternalCanvass)
    End Select

    show_info(txtProduct.Text)
    txtQTY.Focus()
    '...any other code before ending the sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

Make a `Sub` inside a `Class` file that takes the form and those options as parameters, reference the form `ByRef`, make sure all your variables are declared `Public`

```
Public Sub DoMyFormThing(ByRef TheForm as Form)
    With TheForm
        .txtProduct.Enabled = False
        .txtProduct.Text = .pr_code
        .txtDesc.Text = .description
        .txtUnit.Text = .UOMstr
        .txtQTY.Text = .qty
        .txtPurpose.Text = .remarks
        .uom_id = .UOM
        .show_info(.txtProduct.Text)
        .txtQTY.Focus()
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [Passing Arguments by Value and by Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference) and [ByRef vs ByVal Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383167/byref-vs-byval-clarification).

Comment: ByRef is inappropriate here. Also, 'Form' does not have these properties.

Comment: I know, those properties are clearly variables, I was giving the layout as an example.